# Можно ли сдвинуть круговую диаграмму в сторону? Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Я нарисовал круговую диаграмму **matplotlib.pyplot.pie**
[image: Исходный график]

Мне нужно получить что-то вроде такого
[image: Желаемый результат]

Пробовал через tight_layout, margins. Но не получилось - диаграмма также остается в центре. Размер желательно оставить тем же что и показан

Comment: На будущее, приводите в вопросе пример своего кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если пытаться менять параметр center метода pie, то нужно будет долго помучиться, чтобы он заработал. Кроме того, любой модификатор tight_layout всё равно всё сломает.
Поэтому я рекомендовал бы просто рисовать два холста на фигуре по горизонтали - в левом ваша диаграмма, а правый - пустой:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pies = [25, 45, 30]

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(10,5))
ax1.pie(pies, startangle=0)
ax2.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]